# Cannot change existdb-login.html

Tags: html, authentication, exist-db

I am trying to change the login path /exist/app/ to /own-project/app/ in
`dashboard-2.0.9/bower_components/existdb-launcher/existdb-login.html`
but it fails with

The XML parser reported a problem: fatal error at (1,1236) : The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "". XMLDB reported an exception while storing document: The XML parser reported a problem: fatal error at (1,1236) : The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Is it possible that exist does not accept its own scripts?
I know xml is stricter than html but it should be possible to save it(?)
Up to version 5.3.1 it also worked

Thanks!
Gordon

Comment: Could you clarify what action results in this error? Regarding eXist's limited ability to store HTML that is non-well-formed XML, please see https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/pull/836.

Comment: If I change the file mentioned above with exide and try to save then I get the error message.
I found a workaround by changing the file directly in the home directory of the exist db and then restarting it